# Backbone 1.0 js events still attached after .html([content])

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

The problem I am having is click events keep piling up (still attached after changing the view). I have fixed the problem by only having one instance of the view (shown below). I thought backbone got rid of events when the markup is changed. I haven't had this problem with other views.

BROKEN CODE: Click events keep piling up on loadPlayerCard as more views are created.

```
//Player Thumb View
PgaPlayersApp.PlayerThumbView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click': 'loadPlayerCard'
    },
    tagName: 'li',
    template: _.template( $('#player_thumb').html()),    
    render: function()
    {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    loadPlayerCard: function()
    {
        new PlayerCardView({model: this.model}).render();
        return false;
    }
});

//Router
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
      '': 'loadPlayers'
    },

    loadPlayers: function()
    {
        PgaPlayersApp.Players.fetch({reset: true, success: function()
        {
            //When players is first fetched, we want to render the first player into the card area
            new PlayerCardView({model: PgaPlayersApp.Players.first()}).render();

        }});
    }
});

PgaPlayersApp.Router = new Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

FIXED CODE: Code that fixes the problem:

```
PgaPlayersApp.CurrentPlayerCard = new PlayerCardView();

//Player Thumb View
PgaPlayersApp.PlayerThumbView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click': 'loadPlayerCard'
    },
    tagName: 'li',
    template: _.template( $('#player_thumb').html()),    
    render: function()
    {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    loadPlayerCard: function()
    {
        PgaPlayersApp.CurrentPlayerCard.model = this.model;
        PgaPlayersApp.CurrentPlayerCard.render();
        return false;
    }
});

//Router
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
      '': 'loadPlayers'
    },

    loadPlayers: function()
    {
        PgaPlayersApp.Players.fetch({reset: true, success: function()
        {
            //When players is first fetched, we want to render the first player into the card area
            PgaPlayersApp.CurrentPlayerCard.model = PgaPlayersApp.Players.first();
            PgaPlayersApp.CurrentPlayerCard.render();
        }});
    }
});

PgaPlayersApp.Router = new Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

PlayerCardView (For reference):

```
var PlayerCardView = PgaPlayersApp.PlayerCardView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click': 'flipCard'
    },
    el: '#pga_player_card',
    template: _.template( $('#player_card').html()),
    render: function()
    {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    flipCard: function()
    {
        this.$("#player_card_container").toggleClass('flip');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your router you keep creating new `PlayerCardView`s:

```
new PlayerCardView({model: PgaPlayersApp.Players.first()}).render();
```

All of those views share exactly the same `el`:

```
el: '#pga_player_card'
```

So you keep creating new `PlayerCardView`s and each one binds to `#pga_player_card`.

Every time you do that, you bind a brand new view to exactly the same DOM element and each of those views will call [`delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) to bind the event handlers. Note that `delegateEvents` binds to `el` and that [jQuery's `html` method](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

> removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the new content.

So `html` does nothing to `el` but it will remove event handlers from *child elements*. Consider this simple example with `<div id="d"></div>`:

```
$('#d').on('click', function() {
    console.log('Before .html');
});
$('#d').html('<p>Where is pancakes house?</p>');
$('#d').on('click', function() {
    console.log('After .html');
});
```

If you then click on `#d`, you'll see both the before and after messages in the console.

> Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ftJtS/

That simple example is, more or less, equivalent to what you're doing.

You'll have a better time if you:

1. Put the view *inside* `#pga_player_card` and let the router do `$('#pga_player_card').append(view.render().el)`.
2. Keep track of the view that's already there and `view.remove()` it before adding the new one.

Avoid trying to reuse DOM elements for multiple view instances and avoid trying to reuse views, neither is worth the hassle.